# How to traverse in OrientDB and find all longest path?

Tags: orientdb

I'm New to OrientDB, How should I traverse in OrientDB to find all the longest Path irrespective of direction, also find all closed paths?

Comment: are you looking for specific edge to traverse ?

Comment: You can try with $path in projection with traverse sub-query which will return traverse path for individual record. Which you can use for further calculations.